# While running ActiveMQ Artemis master suddenly getting below running in the master console

Tags: activemq-artemis

```
2023-09-17 09:13:56,207 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222149: Sending message Reference[19330395685]:RELIABLE:CoreMessage[messageID=19330395685,durable=true,userID=02c09067-5521-11ee-baa4-0050568e2645,priority=4, timestamp=Sun Sep 17 09:11:16 AST 2023,expiration=0, durable=true, address=t24TWSQueue,size=2275,properties=TypedProperties[__HDR_dlqDeliveryFailureCause=java.lang.Throwable: Exceeded ra redelivery policy limit:RedeliveryPolicy {destination = null, collisionAvoidanceFactor = 0.15, maximumRedeliveries = 0, maximumRedeliveryDelay = 0, initialRedeliveryDelay = 0, useCollisionAvoidance = false, useExponentialBackOff = false, backOffMultiplier = 0.0, redeliveryDelay = 0},_AMQ_GROUP_SEQUENCE=0,JMSReplyTo=queue://t24TWSReplyQueue,__HDR_BROKER_IN_TIME=1694931076352,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1,__HDR_ARRIVAL=0,__HDR_COMMAND_ID=372,JMSCorrelationID=d78cb4bf058cc1b4A3af05bc718a9a0357a3A7fd32513616c7e74d29d5b9,__HDR_PRODUCER_ID=ID:PRO-T24-WEB-01-50564-1694801583409-1:1:2:5,_AMQ_DUPL_ID=ID:PRO-T24-WEB-01-50564-1694801583409-1:1:2:5:1,__HDR_MESSAGE_ID=ID:PRO-T24-WEB-01-50564-1694801583409-1:1:2:5:1,__HDR_DROPPABLE=false]]@820415325 to Dead Letter Address DLQ from t24TWSQueue
2023-09-17 09:48:27,571 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Logging in user: admin
2023-09-17 10:29:28,733 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.SessionExpiryFilter] Expiring session due to inactivity
2023-09-17 11:19:29,041 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64471 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
2023-09-17 11:19:31,039 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64580 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
2023-09-17 11:19:35,165 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.16.8.100:64378 has been detected: Connection reset [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-09-17 11:19:37,055 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
2023-09-17 11:19:37,055 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64471 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
2023-09-17 11:19:37,055 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64471 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
2023-09-17 11:19:37,071 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64919 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
2023-09-17 11:19:39,032 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
2023-09-17 11:19:39,047 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64580 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
2023-09-17 11:19:39,047 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64580 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
2023-09-17 11:19:39,047 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:65069 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
2023-09-17 11:19:43,191 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.16.8.100:64777 has been detected: Connection reset [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-09-17 11:19:43,222 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwCon
```

this is my broker.xml

```xml
     <acceptors>
           <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
       </acceptors>
```

Suggest me the issue for the solution because connection error from client server to artemis server may be need to enable any port for MQTT,STOMP, already added in the acceptor in `broker.xml`.

Comment: suggest me the issue for the solution because connection error from client server to artemis server may be need to enable any port for MQTT,STOMP, already added in the acceptor in broker.xml

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have client applications using the core protocol but attempting to use acceptors which have not been configured to support the core protocol. The following log messages demonstrate this:

```
2023-09-17 11:19:29,041 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64471 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
2023-09-17 11:19:31,039 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64580 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
...
2023-09-17 11:19:37,055 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64471 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
2023-09-17 11:19:37,055 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64471 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
2023-09-17 11:19:37,071 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64919 to /172.16.6.55:1883; protocol CORE not found in map: [MQTT]
...
2023-09-17 11:19:39,047 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64580 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
2023-09-17 11:19:39,047 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:64580 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
2023-09-17 11:19:39,047 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224096: Error setting up connection from /172.16.8.100:65069 to /172.16.6.55:61613; protocol CORE not found in map: [STOMP]
```

The **only** `acceptor` in your `broker.xml` which is configured to support the core protocol is listening on `61616`, i.e.:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
```

If you want other acceptors to support the core protocol then you need to update the `protocols` URL parameter to include `CORE`, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP,CORE;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
<acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT,CORE;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
```

Comment: Okay Justin, Thank you so much Let me add the CORE 
<acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP,CORE;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
like this for everything

Comment: instant of adding CORE in the each acceptor which is suggest you, I am using below type that's fine justin ?
<acceptor name="core">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: worked fine thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future. Thanks!